# How to check consumer offsets when the offset store is Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka

From 0.8.1.1 release, Kafka provides the provision for storage of offsets in Kafka, instead of Zookeeper (see [this](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Committing+and+fetching+consumer+offsets+in+Kafka)). 
I'm not able to figure out how to check the details of offsets consumed, as the current tools only provide consumer offset count checks for zookeeper only.(I'm referring to [this](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/System+Tools#SystemTools-ConsumerOffsetChecker))

If there are any tools available to check consumer offset, please let me know.

Comment: The OffsetChecker works well with offsets stored in Kafka.

Comment: @leshkin Are you talking about the kafka.tools.ConsumerOffsetChecker that comes bundled in the /bin?

Comment: yes, see my answer for details.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'am using kafka 0.8.2 with offsets stored in kafka. This tools works good for me:

```
./kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.ConsumerOffsetChecker 
        --topic your-topic 
        --group your-consumer-group
        --zookeeper localhost:2181
```

You get all informations you need: topic size, consumer lag, owner.

Comment: There is a bug in this code. When I'm storing offsets in kafka, this class looks at /kafka/consumers/crm-client/<offsets>. But my offsets are not present here, since I'm pushing to kafka.

Comment: @g33kb0ne Hm. Can you please post your producer config here.

Comment: Can I get offset of a consumer in the past, does kafka store the offset for each time period

Comment: @krishna222 AFAIK you can either store the offsets in ZK or you push all your consumer offsets to kafka. So, it's possible to fetch the consumer offset topic and teoretically get some kind of timestamp of the consumer offset.

Answer (score 8):

The following straight command gives the enough details:

```
kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe --group my-second-application
```

You will get the details like this

```
TOPIC           PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG             CONSUMER-ID                                     HOST            CLIENT-ID
first_topic     0          4               4               0               consumer-1-7cb31cf3-1621-4635-8f95-6ae85215b31b /10.200.237.53  consumer-1
first_topic     1          3               3               0               consumer-1-7cb31cf3-1621-4635-8f95-6ae85215b31b /10.200.237.53  consumer-1
first_topic     2          3               3               0               consumer-1-7cb31cf3-1621-4635-8f95-6ae85215b31b /10.200.237.53  consumer-1
first-topic     0          4               4               0               -                                               -               -
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm using Kafka 2.1 and I use `kafka-consumer-groups` command which gives useful details like current offset, log-end offset, lag, etc. The simplest command syntax is

```
kafka-consumer-groups.sh            \
--bootstrap-server localhost:29092  \
--describe --group <consumer group name>
```

And the sample output looks like this

```
TOPIC       PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG  CONSUMER-ID            HOST      CLIENT-ID
your.topic  1          17721650        17721673        23   consumer-159-beb9050b  /1.2.3.4  consumer-159
your.topic  3          17718700        17718719        19   consumer-159-beb9050b  /1.2.3.4  consumer-159
your.topic  0          17721700        17721717        17   consumer-159-beb9050b  /1.2.3.4  consumer-159
```

HTH

Comment: it doesnt work when the group is no longer connected with the topic