# Kafka Consumer offset fetch

Tags: apache-kafka

I am using a kafka version where the offset storage is kafka i.e._consumer_offsets

How to retrieve the consumer offset ,when the consumer is down or inactive?

Comment: Any clues as to language / library you are using, or are you wanting bash shell command to fetch them?

Comment: Hello Andrew,  i am using the following command to check offset for active concumer kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server locahost:9092 --describe --new-consumer --group <<groupId>>

Comment: But for inactive consumer, i am unable to find any kafka command tool

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check consumer offsets when the offset store is Kafka?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34019386/how-to-check-consumer-offsets-when-the-offset-store-is-kafka)

Answer (score 0):

Below Command work but with a flaw that it reads from beginning not the latest one

kafka-console-consumer --consumer.config /tmp/consumer.config --formatter "kafka.coordinator.GroupMetadataManager\$OffsetsMessageFormatter" --zookeeper <> --topic __consumer_offsets --from-beginning

Comment: Would really appreciate , If some one find a effective way

Answer (score 0):

If your consumer is down and you want last committed offset of the topic for the specific group please refer to the below mentioned sources

https://github.com/yahoo/kafka-manager

[KafkaConsumerOffsets](https://www.ctheu.com/2017/08/07/looking-at-kafka-s-consumers-offsets/)